# Issues with Scipy.optimize.fsolve on a numba'd function

Tags: python, scipy, numba, scipy-optimize, fsolve

I'm working on trying to find zeros of a function that I've used numba for using scipy.optimize.fsolve. The function is below. The exact details aren't important, but the jist is that F_curr is a 2D numpy array that stores information on the occupancy of some states. This collision integral "I" is the right-hand side of the differential equation dF/dt = I. I want to find steady state solutions to this differential equation, which I would do with scipy.optimize.fsolve.

```
@njit
def collision_integral(F_curr, mu, beta, Omega, G_matrix, momenta_arr, m_cutoff, floquet_spectrum_dict, num_bands = 2):
    
    num_k_pts = momenta_arr.shape[0]
    
    I_curr = np.zeros(F_curr.shape, dtype = numba.double)
    
    for k1_idx in range(0, num_k_pts):
        for alpha in range(0, num_bands):
            # at this level, we are about to set the value of the collision integral at index k, alpha
            
            temp = 0
            
            for k2_idx in range(0, num_k_pts):
                for alpha_p in range(0, num_bands):
                    for n in range(0, 2*m_cutoff + 1):
                        # this is the G term
                        G_term = np.abs(G_matrix[k1_idx, k2_idx, alpha, alpha_p, n])**2
                        
                        # this is to compute the middle curly bracket terms
                        q = momenta_arr[k1_idx] - momenta_arr[k2_idx]
                        omega = phonon_dispersion(q, 1)
                        phonon_occupancy = bose_einstein(omega + 0.01, mu, beta)
                        
                        F_term_1 = F_curr[k2_idx, alpha_p] * (1 - F_curr[k1_idx, alpha]) * phonon_occupancy
                        F_term_1 -= F_curr[k1_idx, alpha] * (1 - F_curr[k2_idx, alpha_p]) * (1 + phonon_occupancy)
                        
                        F_term_2 = F_curr[k2_idx, alpha_p] * (1 - F_curr[k1_idx, alpha]) * (1 + phonon_occupancy)
                        F_term_2 -= F_curr[k1_idx, alpha] * (1 - F_curr[k2_idx, alpha_p]) * phonon_occupancy 
                        
                        # this is the last delta function term to enforce energy conservation
                        # because of how discretized my k points are, I will use a larger broadening paramter
                        delta_1 = delta1D(floquet_spectrum_dict[k1_idx, alpha] - floquet_spectrum_dict[k2_idx, alpha_p]
                                         - omega - (n - m_cutoff) * Omega, eta = 0.02)
                        
                        delta_2 = delta1D(floquet_spectrum_dict[k2_idx, alpha_p] - floquet_spectrum_dict[k1_idx, alpha] 
                                         - omega + (n - m_cutoff) * Omega, eta = 0.02)
                        
                        temp += G_term*(F_term_1 * delta_1 + F_term_2 * delta_2)
            
            # update the collision integral once the triple sum is performed       
            I_curr[k1_idx, alpha] = np.real(temp)
            
            #print(f"the point {k1_idx, alpha} has been updated")
    
    return I_curr
```

This function runs fine on its own if I just initialize some parameters and run the function.

However, when I try and run fsolve to find zeros of the collision integral function, which happens in this code block:

```
def update_procedure(F_init, args):
    
    F_final = scipy.optimize.fsolve(collision_integral, F_init, args = args)
    
    return F_final
```

I get the following error:

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [38], in <cell line: 9>()
      5 F_init[:,0] = 1
      6 args = (mu, beta, Omega, G_matrix, momenta_arr, m_cutoff, floquet_spectrum_dict, 2)
----> 9 F_final = update_procedure(F_init, args)

Input In [37], in update_procedure(F_init, args)
      1 def update_procedure(F_init, args):
      2     
      3     #F_final, infodict, ier, mesg = scipy.optimize.fsolve(collision_integral, F_init, args)
      5     print("got here")
----> 7     F_final = scipy.optimize.fsolve(collision_integral, F_init, args = args)
      9     return F_final

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:160, in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
     49 """
     50 Find the roots of a function.
     51 
   (...)
    150 
    151 """
    152 options = {'col_deriv': col_deriv,
    153            'xtol': xtol,
    154            'maxfev': maxfev,
   (...)
    157            'factor': factor,
    158            'diag': diag}
--> 160 res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    161 if full_output:
    162     x = res['x']

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:226, in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    224 if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    225     args = (args,)
--> 226 shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
    227 if epsfcn is None:
    228     epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:24, in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     23                 output_shape=None):
---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

Input In [35], in collision_integral(F_curr, mu, beta, Omega, G_matrix, momenta_arr, m_cutoff, floquet_spectrum_dict, num_bands)
      6 for k1_idx in range(0, num_k_pts):
      7     for alpha in range(0, num_bands):
      8         #print(f"starting {k1_idx}, {alpha}")
      9         # at this level, we are about to set the value of the collision integral at index k, alpha
---> 10         temp = collision_integral_entry(k1_idx, alpha, F_curr, 
     11                                         mu, beta, Omega, G_matrix, momenta_arr, m_cutoff, floquet_spectrum_dict, 
     12                                         num_bands)
     14         # update the collision integral once the triple sum is performed     
     15         I_coll[k1_idx, alpha] = np.real(temp)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(array(float64, 1d, C), UniTuple(int64 x 2))
 
There are 22 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 20 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'getitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
        With argument(s): '(array(float64, 1d, C), UniTuple(int64 x 2))':
       No match.
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'GetItemBuffer.generic': File: numba\core\typing\arraydecl.py: Line 166.
        With argument(s): '(array(float64, 1d, C), UniTuple(int64 x 2))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         NumbaTypeError: cannot index array(float64, 1d, C) with 2 indices: UniTuple(int64 x 2)
  raised from C:\Users\Brandon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\arraydecl.py:88

During: typing of intrinsic-call at C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13188\2614269881.py (19)

File "..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13188\2614269881.py", line 19:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Which looks as though there's an issue with accessing/setting an entry in an array via numba.

One important thing about the function: I benchmarked my code with and without numba, and numba is giving ~50x performance increase - I don't think that un-jitting my code is in the realm of possibility without some serious rewrite.

The first thing I tried doing was running a similar notebook with a jitted function inside the scipy.fsolve function, and this ran fine. The problem doesn't seem to be numba'd functions inside fsolve on its own:

```
@njit
def my_func(a):
    return np.vdot(a, np.ones((len(a)))) * a - np.ones(len(a))

def solver(initial_guess):
    return scipy.optimize.fsolve(my_func, initial_guess)

initial_guess = np.ones(10)
x = solver(initial_guess)

print(x)
```

Then, I was wondering if scipy might be messing with datatypes, resulting in an error when I tried setting the array entry in the line

```
I_curr[k1_idx, alpha] = np.real(temp)
```

The reason I thought this would be the case is because I'd ran into errors before when, for example, initializing np.zeros() in a numba'd function, which were resolved by adding something along the lines of "dtype = numba.double". I tried using a wrapper function to fix datatypes with something like ".astype(numba.double)" , but that doesn't seem to work either.

I then thought it might have been an issue with setting array entries, so I split the numba function into two parts, where the assignment "I_curr[k1_idx, alpha] = np.real(temp)" was not in a numba function, but the inner-most three for loops were. No array assignment was happening inside a numba function, but this also didn't resolve the issue. It seems to be a problem with accessing?

At this point I'm really not sure what to do or where the exact issue is arising. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: line 24 shows how scipy is calling your function, `res = atleast_1d(thefunc(...`.  Test the arguments it supplies for type, shape and dtype.You can do that  with a python function.  Your function has to accept those.  I won't try to guess as to why numba has problems with those.  And reread the scipy docs.  That's the boss.

Comment: What happens if you are explicit in initializing `I_curr`?  E.g., `I_curr = np.zeros((num_k_pts, num_bands), dtype = numba.double)`

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the replies! This ended up getting resolved - it wasn't a Numba issue, it was that fsolve flattens the array and my function expects a 2D one, so there would be a shape mismatch.